# External hard drive not usable on Windows, but works on Mac - how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, ntfs

My 4TB Western Digital MyBook hard drive has gradually stopped working in Windows 10. When it does show, it only works for a minute then the system behaves as if the drive is not available - even though explorer shows it still being present. Files can be seen, but not read, written, or executed. DSKMGMT does not show its presence.

I figured I'd try it on my mac and voila - its pseudo NTFS drivers let it work in read mode just fine.

Then I thought I would install Paragon's NTFS drivers to gain write mode.
After that the mac no longer recognized the drive! Uninstalling Paragon let it read the drive again (read mode only of course).

So now -- any ideas how I can get the thing working on my PC? Sound like a CHKDSK fix? How to proceed if I can't even start the drive?

Comment: Please use a SMART monitoring program to verify that the drive is not defective.  If it is defective, pull off as much data as you can as it's likely going to die soon.

Comment: changed the wording, and the drive is certainly on its last legs - that's why I'm pulling the data from mac - over the network